# How to upload a data frame into a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: r, google-sheets

I would like to upload a data frame into one particular workingsheet within a spreadsheet on Google Spreadsheet using:

```
        googlesheets library

        https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets
```

Usually, its possible to upload a whole spreadsheet using the:

```
upload_ss("data.xlsx", sheet_title = "Year", verbose = TRUE)
```

or individual sheets with either

```
Year <- Year %>% edit_cells(input = data, header = TRUE, trim = FALSE)
Year <- edit_cells(Year,input = data, header = TRUE, trim = FALSE)
```

However, when trying to access a particular (working)sheet:

```
Year <- edit_cells(Year, ws = "January", input = dataJan, header = TRUE, trim = FALSE)
```

I'll always get an error:

```
Error in get_ws(ss, ws, verbose = FALSE) : Worksheet January not found
```

Does anyone experienced similar issues or found solutions?

Answer (score 3):

First register the Speadsheet:

```
  Test<- register_ss("Year")
```

Second access Workingsheet:

```
  test<- edit_cells(Year, ws = "January", input = Test, header = TRUE, trim = FALSE)
```